# running CLion on windows on different user

Tags: windows, windows-10, ide

I updated CLion under a different user on Windows 10 and now I can't start it because it gets an error:
[image]

It doesn't even start when I "Run as administrator", which is strange, because I am the administrator (I checked).

I've given myself full access to this executable via `Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Permissions` but it still doesn't work:

[image]

Then I've given myself full access to `clion64.exe.vmoptions` and got this error:

[image]

How can I give full control to ALL FILES in this goddamn folder (CLion 2020.3.3)?

I've already done this, by the way, but Windows does not acknowledge:

[image]

If anyone knows how to fix this issue, please, help!